# Sqlite3 Operational Error: near "REFERENCES" Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
with sqlite3.connect('notDataBase1.db') as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """CREATE TABLE OrderDetails
                (OrderDetailsID INTEGER,
                 OrderID INTEGER,
                 ProductID INTEGER,
                 PRIMARY KEY(OrderDetailsID),
                 FOREIGN KEY(OrderID REFERENCES
                             Orders(OrderID)),
                 FOREIGN KEY(ProductID REFERENCES
                             Products(ProductID)))"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Which gives me the error:

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "REFERENCES": syntax error

I'm not sure what has happened as this code worked for me yesterday, but has since stopped working.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does you DB have Orders and Products table?

```
CREATE TABLE `OrderDetails` (
    `OrderDetailsID `   INTEGER,
    `OrderID `  INTEGER,
    `ProductID `    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(`ProductID `) REFERENCES `Products`(`ProductsID`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`OrderID `) REFERENCES `Orders`(`OrdersID`),
    PRIMARY KEY(`OrderDetailsID `)
);
```

The sql above works, I think your mistake comes from the Foreign Key part, bad english sorry. As you can see, the References part must be out of the Foreign key attribute. Give it a try and tell me.

Have a nice day